# Limit of: $ -x+\sqrt{x^2+x} $ for $ x\to\infty $

Tags: calculus, limits

Why the solution of this limit: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}-x+\sqrt{x^2+x} $$ is $\frac{1}{2}$?

I tried to do De L'hopital to $$\frac{-x^2+x\sqrt{x^2+x}}{x}$$ but whitout success.

Comment: Do you know about multiplying by the *conjugate*?

Comment: The limit does not come out to 0/0 or inf/inf so L'hospital's rule is not valid. Instead, try multiplying and dividing by $-x - \sqrt{x^2 + x}$

Comment: The Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+y}$ as $y\to 0$, if you know about Taylor expansion, is $1+y/2+O(y^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
-x+\sqrt{x^2+x}&=-x+\sqrt{x^2+x}\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+x}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+x}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{x}{x+\sqrt{x^2+x}}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1+1/x}}\to 1/2\,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to \infty
\end{align}$$

Comment: @coffeemath I'll also delete.  And thank you much!!  - Mark

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the expression as $x( \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}} -1)$ and then expand the square root in binomial coefficients, use the first two. What do you get?